# Multi currency test class

Tags: apex, code-coverage

So we are planning to turn on multi currency for a customer org.

Ive been reading up on the Apex changes required for queries, etc.

But Im not sure how to handle our test classes. Our build org will not be multi currency because this is only for a single product used by a limited number of customers. So can I do anything with my existing test classes to limit the code coverage reduction that will occur from adding lines specifically for orgs where multi currency is turned on?

Comment: I have multicurrency turned on and as far as I know I'm not doing anything specific with my tests to ensure that it's taking multi currency into account. 

Are you sure that you *have* to make changes? Like does your code do a lot of things with currency fields and numbers that you're afraid it will not compile or a test will not pass?

Comment: sorry about the massive delay. Im more worried about code coverage and ensuring that the code works for multi currency orgs when changes are made.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using the `UserInfo.isMultiCurrencyOrganization()` method in our code to ensure that we dont get compile/runtime error for our managed package code.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).